# Bootstrap popover trigger e html option juntos não funcionam

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Alguém sabe porque quando eu coloco o trigger junto com o html:true o popover para de funcionar?

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="popoverr" role="button" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue.">
   <i class="fa fa-money"></i> 10 Pontos
</a>
```

JS:

```
$(".popoverr").popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'focus' // comente o trigger para o popover funcionar.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rf2Dr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `focus` faz mais sentido para inputs, não para elementos.
A minha sugestão é usar ambos `hover click`.

```
$(".popoverr").popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'click hover'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rf2Dr/1/

Comment: Alguma diferença se usado apenas o `hover`? Sempre utilizo hover.. Boa resposta :)

Comment: @RonnyAmarante o `hover` somente funciona bem. O `click` é util para "mobiles/tablets" que não têm `hover`

Comment: Boa, não havia pensado nessa hipótese. :)

Comment: Perfeito, eu precisava da função click também justamente por causa de o projeto ser mobile-ready.